# Translate Vim keycode string ("<C-Z>") into actual keycode number (^Z = 26) in Python

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to port my Vim 8.0 configuration (`~/.vimrc`) to Python. That is, I'm setting Vim options as fields on `vim.options` mapping:

```
import vim

# set wildmenu
vim.options['wildmenu'] = True
# set wildcharm=<C-Z>
vim.options['wildcharm'] = ord('^Z') # [Literal ^Z (ASCII 26), CTRL-V CTRL-Z]
# set wildchar=<F10>
vim.options['wildchar'] = -15211 # extracted from Vim
```

The `wildchar` and `wildcharm` Vim options are of type "number". As far as I understand, they expect a kind of a keycode (at least in simple cases it *is* the ASCII code of the character in question).

In Vimscript, when you say something like `set wildchar=<F10>`, Vim translates the Vim-specific textual representation into a numeric keycode. 
In Python, this is not the case (`vim.options['wildchar'] = '<F10>'` gives a TypeError).

For simple cases, it is possible to use `ord()` on a string containing the literally typed control character (see above with Ctrl-Z). However, a key like `F10` produces multiple characters, so I can't use `ord()` on it.

In the end, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
vim.options['wildchar'] = magic('<F10>')
```

Does this `magic()` function exist?

---

Edit: I'm not asking how to invoke Vimscript code from Python (i. e. `vim.command(...)`).
 I understand that the encompassing problem can be trivially solved this way, but I'm asking a different question here.

Answer (score -1):

```
:python vim.command("set wildchar=<F10>")
```

See the [`vim.command` documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html#python-command) for more explanation.

Comment: This answers a related question, but not the one I asked.

Comment: @sepehr This is certainly not link-only answer. The answer is in the code. The link just points to docs about `vim.command()`.